# Applying Euler Homogenous Function Theorem to $df$ or $f$

Tags: thermodynamics, non-equilibrium

I am currently reading [Demirel's *Nonequilibrium Thermodynamics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444595570) in order to learn more about entropy and nonequlibrium thermodynamics

However I and stumped on how the author's do the following step:

> The pressure $P$ and temperature $T$ define the values at each point of the system and are therefore called *intensive properties*, some of which can be expressed as derivatives of extensive properties, such as temperature
>   $$T=\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N}$$
>   where $U$ is the energy and $S$ is the entropy. If $X$ denotes any extensive property (not necessarily a thermodynamic propert) of a phase, we may derive intensive properties denoted by $X_i$ and called as partial properties $X_i=\left(\partial X/\partial n_i\right)_{T,p,n_i}$ ($i\neq j$). For any partial property we have $dX=\sum_i\left(\partial X/\partial n_i\right)dn_i=\sum_iX_idn_i$ at constant $T$ and $P$. The Euler theorem shows that $X=\sum_iX_in_i$

Is the result from the text obtained from **direct integration**, or it just **looks like it is integrated because of the consequence of Euler Homogeneous Function Theorem?**

That is, is this relation
$$
X=\sum_i X_in_i \tag{1}
$$
the integration of this relation
$$
dX=\sum_i X_idn_i? \tag{2}
$$
But just because of Euler Homogeneous Function Theorem, if (2) is true, then (1) must also be true by the theorem?

Comment: The print in the picture is tough to read.  Also, why (_specifically_) are you confused by this derivation?

Comment: There is no derivation. That is what's confusing. There's a derivation of The Euler Theorem, but not of why the Euler theorem implies the result given on the left.

Comment: At least I think so, otherwise it would be a math question.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I am confused of, the author is saying that by Euler's Theorem, dX=sum (blah d(blah)) goes to X=sum (blah d(blah)) but Euler Theorem only relates f=sum(partials * x), not df=sum (partials * dx)

Thus I don't understand how it is carried out exactly


.If I am just integrating both sides, then I have to rationalize why the partials can be pulled out from the integral and the integral only integrate the differential dX terms

Comment: I just found something that is sort of related
http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60084/why-does-u-t-s-p-v-sum-i-mu-i-n-i?rq=1

.So using this question as a reference, are we actually not integrating, but simply using the property of X being 1st order homogenous so that by Euler Theorem X= sum paritals . n?

Comment: so in the end it LOOKS like as if the expression is being integrated both side, but is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it looks like it's integrated (and sometimes it is even called integrating), but really it is due to the Euler theorem.

Suppose $X$ is a first order homogeneous function of $n_1, n_2, \dots$ (this is equivalent to saying it is extensive) and that $\mathrm{d}X(\mathbf{n}) = \sum_i \frac{\partial X(\mathbf{n})}{\partial n_i}\textrm{d}n_i$. This is to say $\mathrm{d}X(\lambda\mathbf{n}) = \sum_i \frac{\partial X(\lambda\mathbf{n})}{\partial (\lambda n_i)}\textrm{d}(\lambda n_i)$.

Now it is straightforward to write
$$X(\mathbf{n}) = \frac{\partial(\lambda X(\mathbf{n}))}{\partial\lambda} = \frac{\partial X(\lambda\mathbf{n})}{\partial\lambda} = \sum_i \frac{\partial X(\lambda\mathbf{n})}{\partial (\lambda n_i)}\frac{\partial (\lambda n_i)}{\partial\lambda} = \sum_i \frac{\partial X(\lambda\mathbf{n})}{\partial (\lambda n_i)}n_i$$

With $\lambda = 1$ we have
$$X(\mathbf{n}) = \sum_i \frac{\partial X(\mathbf{n})}{\partial n_i}n_i = \sum X_i n_i$$